# geth error log: flag provided but not defined: -dev.period

Tags: go-ethereum

Azure private blockchain i am running in --dev --dev.period 5 mode, i am having the following error:

> "flag provided but not defined: -dev.period"

.
below is sh script to run on azure. i am only running one VM

```
geth --datadir /home/gethadmin/.ethereum -verbosity 4 --bootnodes enode://7b..@:30303 --bootnodes enode://75bxx......@:30303 --maxpeers 25 --nat none --networkid 72 --identity ngpblkioyb4p-tx0 --fast --rpc --rpcaddr 10.0.0.4 --rpccorsdomain * --rpcapi eth,net,web3,admin,personal --dev --dev.period 5 --ws --wsaddr 10.0.0.4 --wsorigins *
```